# Is there a way to indicate that a node is deprecated in an XML file?

Tags: xml, dtd

We are trying to formalize an XML feed that we produce and is in use by external consumers.  Is there a syntax, either within an XML file or in its DTD, to indicate that a particular node is deprecated and will be removed in the future?

Answer (score 2):

(1) You can use XML comments for that `<!-- Document here whatever needed -->`

(2) It is better to use XSDs instead of DTDs. XSDs also have documentation dedicated tags. Please see below.

```
<xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>Document here whatever needed</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
```

Answer (score 0):

Full SGML (as opposed to the XML subset of SGML) has support for marked sections with `INCLUDE` or `IGNORE` (or `TEMP`) as marked section keyword, and the ability to use parameter entities in marked section declarations whereas XML has only `CDATA` marked sections. You'd use it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [
  ...
  <!ENTITY % legacy "INCLUDE">
 ]>
...
<![ %legacy [
  <elmt>Deprecated content</elmt>
]>
```

or even using `TEMP` as a dedicated construct to markup editorial content:

```
<![ TEMP [
  <elmt>...</elmt>
]>
```

While this can't readily be a used with (just) XML (ie. unless you're using SGML for XML authoring), I thought this might still inform an XML-based design in such a way that it carries over to and is aligned with SGML. Specifically, you'd use a dedicated XML element to wrap content deemed deprecated, rather than using eg. attributes for this purpose.